# Cambiar color StatusBar

Tags: java, android

Cómo puedo cambiar el color de la StatusBar desde la clase java?
Por ejemplo, para cambiar el color de la barra de navegación (la inferior de atrás, home y menú) sería así:

> getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorbarra_inf));

También me interesaría desde ***color*** o ***style*** pero no puedo porque en ***AndroidManifest*** cambie el Theme ***AppTheme*** por ***Theme.AppCompat.Light*** para usar la App en blanco y no colores negros, y ahora al cambiar el colorPrimary no hace efecto.

Style:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una opción si tu app tiene como minimo el API 21 es agrega la propiedad `android:statusBarColor` a tu estilo, definiendo el color deseado:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

  <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>

</style>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es importante comentar que esto aplicaría para todas las Activities de tu aplicación que usen el tema.

Otra opción es usar [setStatusBarColor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)), de esta forma:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);  //Define color blanco.
```

o de esta definiendo el color dentro de `colors.xml` :

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.blanco)); //Define color blanco.
```

Comment: Gracias! Solucionado, solo he tenido que añadir (getResources().getColor(R.color.colorbarra)); para añadir el color desde el xml colors @Jorgesys

Comment: Excelente, agregué dos opciones,saludos! ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ