# Android Studio ¿Como cambio el color de fondo y texto de la Status Bar?

Tags: android, android-studio, status-bar, text-color, background

**Descripción**

Tengo una status bar de color negro con letras de color negro. Me gustaría poder cambiar el color de fondo de la Status bar a un color negro pero transparente y las letras a un color blanco.

**Aclaración**

Se que hay varias preguntas de esto pero ninguna me funcionó.

Leí varias y todas decían que se solucionaba con esto:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
```

o usando esto en styles:

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

**Edit (14/02/2020)**

Descubrí que debajo de la API 23, se puede cambiar el color del texto de la status bar a negro o blanco. 
Este cambio de color depende de la siguiente propiedad que se ubica en "styles.xml":

true

Si asignamos un "theme" a nuestra actividad el cual tenga esta propiedad, el color de texto de la Status Bar va a ser negro. De lo contrario, será blanco.

**Nuevo problema:**

Sabiendo esto, intenté crear un nuevo estilo en **styles.xml** que contenga dicha propiedad porque necesito asignar el color de texto de la status bar a color negro para algunas actividades, y blanco para otras. Este estilo lo asigné en "themes" a algunas actividades por medio del manifest pero obtengo el siguiente error el cual me gustaría me ayuden a solucionar:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

**Todavía no pude solucionar este problema. Gracias por leer!**

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a esta pregunta, se indica como cambiar el color del `StatusBar`:

[Cambiar color StatusBar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46871/cambiar-color-statusbar)

Pero en este caso deseas "Status bar a un color negro pero transparente y las letras a un color blanco.". Cambiar el texto de color no es posible pero en este caso puedes realizar un "truco" de esta forma:

Define un color negro en `colors.xml` y cárgalo en `onCreate()` de tu Activity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.black));

...
...
}
```

de esta forma obtendrías:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solo me funcionó el setStatusBarColor, que pude cambiar la status a color negro. Pero las letras siguen quedando en color negro. El getDecorView no funcionó. QUe puede ser?

Comment: No se muestra como en la imagen? definiste un color negro dentro de colors.xml así:     <color name="black">#000000</color> ?

Comment: Sí. Hice lo que me dijiste!

Comment: Me parece que le pifiaste al usar el flag SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR, este parametro te pone las letras en negro para soportar un statusbar de color clarito, si lo quieres en negro no necesitas este flag.

Comment: Gracias por comentar Erick. Entonces que tengo que hacer para obtener un background negro y text color blanco?

Comment: Realizé un edit a la publicación. Ayuda por favor!